# Layout background color dimmed after onResume

Tags: android, android-layout, android-color

In my application I face the strange color issue.

If I load the first time it show the correct color.- No issues

**My problem:**

If I move to another fragment or another activity & then If I return back my layout background color get changed

Some notes about my layouts,

1. I am set the background color from xml layouts only.
2. No run time background color modification code in java.

What I am tried,

I searched in google & also stackoverflow questions. But no similar questions are not found. So I ask this question.

anybody face this kind of issue?

**My original color background**

[image]

**After onResume I get strange color like dimmed color**
[image]

Comment: Have you updated the color of the headers in onResume method?@Ranjith

Comment: No. In java no code for color updation